# Angular and rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Interface (Cars). I declared a value cars: Cars; I want to use map and get properties (model and yearOfIssue) and then set it to the values models and yearsOfIssue 
 I have read about mergeMap, should I use it here? And if should, how to?

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'rxjs';

  cars: Cars[] = [
    {
      model: 'bmw',
      yearOfIssue: ['1992', '1997', '2002'],
    },
  ];
  models = '';
  yearsOfIssue: string[] = [];



    ngOnInit() {
        of(this.cars).pipe(map((x) => x.map((xe) => xe)));
      }
    }

    export interface Cars {
      model: string;
      yearOfIssue: string[];
    }
```

I need something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
            of(this.cars)
.pipe(map((x) => this.models = x.model)(map(x) => this.yearsOfIssue = x.yearOfIssue);
              }
```

Comment: I'm not really following what you want here?

Comment: I have an Interface (Cars). I declared a value cars: Cars; I want to use map and get properties (model and yearOfIssue) and then set it to the values models and yearsOfIssue

Comment: rxjs is for dealing with streams of data, not a static value like you have here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS has nothing to do here. You could achieve it with array `map` method. Try the following

```js
var cars = [{ model: 'bmw', yearOfIssue: ['1992', '1997', '2002'] }, { model: 'audi', yearOfIssue: ['1987', '1995', '2008'] }];

var models = cars.map(car => car.model);
var yearsOfIssue = cars.map(car => car.yearOfIssue);

console.log(models);
console.log(yearsOfIssue);
```

Typescript

```js
export interface Cars {
  model: string;
  yearOfIssue: string[];
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Cars[] = [{
    model: 'bmw',
    yearOfIssue: ['1992', '1997', '2002'],
  }];

  models: any = [];
  yearsOfIssue: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.models = this.cars.map(car => car.model);
    this.yearsOfIssue = this.cars.map(car => car.yearOfIssue);
  }
}
```

Comment: ty, but I just using a simple code to explain of my trouble, How can I do, exactly that I wrote in OnInit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the RxJs map try this:

```
.pipe(
    map((x) => {
        this.models = x.model;
        this.yearsOfIssue = x.yearOfIssue;
        return x;
    })
);
```